# cakephp: how can i set an fields-options like "only fields not null"

Tags: cakephp, find, field

is there an option in the find-method of cake, where i can say "give me only fields that ore not null"? I dont want to put this condition seperatly for every field in the condition-array, better to set this as an option in the fields array like this.

```
$this->find('first',array(
      'fields' => array("not" => null)
));
```

Or even to exclude fields like this.

```
 $this->find('first' array(
      'fields' => array('not' => array('id','created','modified'))
```

));

Thanks,
Guido

Answer (score 0):

It's going to have to be a condition (why is it a problem as a condition?).

But, you can put it in a `beforeFind()` method, so you don't have to add the condition to each query.  Putting it in a `beforeFind()` will make the condition get appended to every query before it actually runs the find.  Sounds like what I assume you really want, since "but not as a condition" doesn't really give much reasoning why it can't be.

Comment: Hi Dave, 
thanks.
i think, i found a solution for filtering the NULL-fields. But not in the fields-option, i found the static method Set::filter. So i can filter my data like this:
    $this->set(Set::filter($this->SomeModel->find('first')));

Comment: I've got a problem with setting up y condition because the fields should be set several hasOne and has many joins in the class-head. The tables have many columns, and it would be easier (even when its possible :)) to say "no null-fields at all" or to list the fields like "id, created and modified" which i don't want to read.

Comment: So i can use conditions, sure, but it would be nice for me to set this option in another way, even when its possible.

Thank you very much ;)

Comment: What you listed as an option is just removing empty items from the array after you've already done the `find()`.  If that's what you were hoping to do, you REALLY should have clarified in your question.